# React render FusionChart consuming API Rest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api, charts

I am trying to create a chart consuming an api rest, however, it is not working. The message "No data to display" appears. I've tried with Chartjs and Echarts and the same error appears. Could someone help me by pointing me out where I'm going wrong?

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
import Charts from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts";
import ReactFC from "react-fusioncharts";
import FusionTheme from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion";

ReactFC.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FusionTheme);

Charts(FusionCharts);

const dataSource = {
  "chart": {
    "caption": "Market Share of Web Servers",
    "plottooltext": "<b>$percentValue</b> of web servers run on $label servers",
    "showlegend": "1",
    "showpercentvalues": "1",
    "legendposition": "bottom",
    "usedataplotcolorforlabels": "1",
    "theme": "fusion"
  },
  "data": [] 
};

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    pieConfigs: {}
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://private-afe609-testefront.apiary-mock.com/anual-percentage")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          pieConfigs: {
            type: "Pie2d",
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            dataFormat: "json",
            dataSource: response
          }
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) return <>Loading..</>;
    return <ReactFC {...this.state.pieConfigs} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataSource structure is not in the proper format, the response which you are getting has the only array of objects, but the datasource takes the value as an object where the data props contain the value which you are getting in response, in react words

```
  pieConfigs: {
            type: "Pie2d",
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            dataFormat: "json",
            dataSource: {
              data: response
            }
          }
```

Here is a sandbox demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-snow-60ch8